# How can i store my user's tasks in different collections in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a simple crud task manager backend. How can i separate the data between the users? For example if one user in one device adds a new task the second user can see, delete and update that task. How can i separate the users without making a login? I searched for a bit about sessions but i don't think that's what i want in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create a uuid whenever someone comes to the page, and save that uuid in user local storage in order to manage the records.